# LaTeX: Statistics CDF and PDF

Tags: math-mode

Is there any way to type the CDF and PDF of a distribution on LaTeX similar to how it's done on this site?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)

Comment: welcome to tex.se! (i) you need to select package by which you will draw thoise funcion (`tikz`, `pgfplots`, `pstricks` etc) (ii) determine function and than draw you function. how to draw, search this site (here are lot of examples how to draw gaussians) or look http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/, if you will use `pgfplots (recommended).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is so unclear that Zarko thought it was "how to draw the graph?" whereas I thought it was "how to type the formulae?".

Let us know who is right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Probability density function:
\[
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b-a}&\text{for $x\in[a,b]$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\]
Cumulative distribution function:
\[
\begin{cases}
0&\text{for $x<a$}\\
\frac{x-a}{b-a}&\text{for $x\in[a,b)$}\\
1&\text{for $x\ge b$}\\
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know it might seem a bit odd, but I find, _e.g._, `\text{for $x\in[a,b]$}` more logical.

Comment: Dear @CarLaTeX, recently happens mee to may times that i misunderstood questions :-( . probably you have right.

Comment: @Zarko I'm sure it's not your fault, questions are often unclear! :)

Comment: And, of course, both I and you are forgetting about the `cases*` environment from the `mathtools` package!  Or `dcases*`, perhaps?

Comment: @GuM In this case ( :) ) it's better if you post your own answer, please!

Comment: @angleofaxis You're welcome, but next time please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Now wait until GuM posts his answer, and then accept the one you prefer: [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852), this is our way to say "thank you"!

Answer (score 2):

I yield to @CarLaTeX’s invite to provide a slightly simplified version of her answer:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}

Probability density function:
\[
    \begin{cases*}
        \frac{1}{b-a} & for $x\in[a,b]$ \\
        0 & otherwise \\
    \end{cases*}
\]

Cumulative distribution function:
\[
    \begin{cases*}
        0 & for $x<a$ \\
        \frac{x-a}{b-a} & for $x\in[a,b)$ \\
        1 & for $x\ge b$ \\
    \end{cases*}
\]

\end{document}
```

See the manual of the `mathtools` package, section 3.4.3 (p. 18) for details.